# Size of the finalizer queue

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, idisposable, finalizer

How can I get the current size of the finalizer queue in c#?

I am trying to debug an application that is a little too liberal with letting the garbage collector dispose IDIsposables, which I suspect is related to occasional crashes.

The IDIsposables in question contain unmanaged memory, and therefore implement their own finalizer, which disposes them if the Dispose method is not called explicitely before they are garbage collected.

The garbage collection handles all finalizable objects in a separate finalizer thread, which can grow if objects are created faster than they are finalized.

It would be a big help if I could output the number of objects currently waiting for finalization at various stages in the program.

The IDisposable objects come from various libraries, so adding logging to the respective finalizers themselves is not trivial. Is there a way to get the number of objects waiting for finalisation, directly from the GC?

Comment: The garbage collector doesn't do anything special for instances of types that implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: Sorry, I am talking about IDisposables that have unmanged resources, and therefore implement their own finalizer

Comment: No problem. You can inspect the content of the queue via SOS if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Memory Performance Counters.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

To use C# you can use WMemoryProfiler which automates debugging from C#. You can even debug your own process if you wish like this:

```
using System;
using WMemoryProfiler;

namespace AllocateManyObjects
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Shows the basic usage of WMemoryProfiler
    /// </summary>
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Start this application not under the debugger
                // To start is press Ctrl+F5 in Visual Studio to start it without debugging.

                SelfDebug();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Got Exception: {0}", ex);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Issue a !Threads command and print the output to console
        /// </summary>
        private static void SelfDebug()
        {
            using (var debugger = new MdbEng())
            {
                string[] output = debugger.Execute("!FinalizeQueue");
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, output));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You only need to download https://wmemoryprofiler.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest
compile the sources and install Windbg from the Windows 8.0 SDK or deploy it to the location where it searches for Windbg:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x64

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86

Then you can parse the output of sos commands or do anything you would like with it.

This sample prints on my machine:

```
0:008> !FinalizeQueue
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll -

************* Symbol Loading Error Summary **************
Module name            Error
clr                    The system cannot find the file specified : srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

You can troubleshoot most symbol related issues by turning on symbol loading diagnostics (!sym noisy) and repeating the command that caused symbols to be loaded.
You should also verify that your symbol search path (.sympath) is correct.
PDB symbol for clr.dll not loaded
SyncBlocks to be cleaned up: 0
Free-Threaded Interfaces to be released: 0
MTA Interfaces to be released: 0
STA Interfaces to be released: 0
----------------------------------
generation 0 has 165 finalizable objects (0000000000a70ed0->0000000000a713f8)
generation 1 has 0 finalizable objects (0000000000a70ed0->0000000000a70ed0)
generation 2 has 0 finalizable objects (0000000000a70ed0->0000000000a70ed0)
Ready for finalization 0 objects (0000000000a713f8->0000000000a713f8)
Statistics for all finalizable objects (including all objects ready for finalization):
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
00007ff84e389230        1           24 System.WeakReference
00007ff84e3874a0        1           32 Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePEFileHandle
00007ff84e397a28        1           88 System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource+OverideEventProvider
00007ff84e36eca8        1          104 System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context
00007ff84e397600        1          160 System.Diagnostics.Tracing.FrameworkEventSource
00007ff84e38a5e0        6          192 Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle
00007ff84e388038        3          192 System.Threading.ReaderWriterLock
00007ff84e384928        7          224 Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle
00007ff84d4298a8        8          256 Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeProcessHandle
00007ff84e3822f8        4          384 System.Threading.Thread
00007ff84e3a15a0       17          544 Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeTokenHandle
00007ff84e38ca60        7          728 System.IO.FileStream
00007ff84d43c908        8         2240 System.Diagnostics.Process
00007ff84d3f94d8      100         5600 System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule
Total 165 objects
0:008> .remote_exit g;
Press Enter to exit.
```

Comment: That looks like a hammer looking for a nail.  Are you spamming your project?  PerformanceCounter is the trivial solution of course.

Comment: Did you find a bug with performance counters? After you know the number is increasing then you do what? Attach Windbg and dump the finalization queue to get an idea which objects are finalized so often. I doubt you will be able to deduce that from performance counters.

Comment: Hmya, it is not what he asked for.

Comment: It might not be the answer what he was asking for but the solution to his problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sos.FinalizeQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764(v=vs.110).aspx) command